# Ocaml : How compile a file using the module Http_Client.Convenience?

Tags: http, ocaml

I'm trying to compile a file using the module Http_Client.Convenience (his documentation is here : [Http_Client.Convenience](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/dl/ocamlnet-3.4.1/doc/html-main/Http_client.Convenience.html)

I have the file foo.ml :

```
let result = Http_client.Convenience.http_put "Foo"
```

I'm compiling with this way :

```
ocamlfind ocamlopt  -o foo -linkpkg -package netclient foo.ml
```

According to this website [Objective Caml](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Getting_started_with_Objective%20Caml), this line should be compile without the following error : "Unbound module Http_client".

What is wrong in my compilation directive ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what worked for me:

```
(* This is curried since http_put takes 2 string and we are only giving 1 
   val Nethttp_client.Convenience.http_put string -> string -> string  *)                     

let result = Nethttp_client.Convenience.http_put "Foo"


ocamlfind ocamlc foo.ml -package netclient -linkpkg -o Foo
```

You could also do

```
    (* This is foo.ml *)
    open Nethttp_client 
    let result = Convenience.http_put "Foo"
```

And then on the command line:

```
   ocamlfind ocamlc foo.ml -package netclient -linkpkg -o Foo
```